# Format \pgfmathresult with \pgfmathprintnumber and using it in \TextField

Tags: pgfmath, pgfmathparse, textfield

I want to use `\pgfmathprintnumber` to format the `\pgfmathresult` but without printing it because I want to then use it in a `\TextField` as value that does not accept `\pgfmathprintnumber` for some ununderstandable reasons.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/fpu = true,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    precision=2,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={.}
}

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathparse{1+2}
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
    \begin{Form}
        \TextField[value={\pgfmathresult}]{}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image].

So this is working I think because the execution of `\pgfmathprintnumber` changes the content of `\pgfmathresult` and all is fine except that I have to print the `\pgfmathprintnumber` in some arbitrary text location to execute the command.

I am trying to hide the output of `\pgfmathprintnumber` behind the `\TextField` with a zero width box but the execution of `\pgfmathprintnumber` seems to be sceduled after the execution of `\pgfmathresult` of the `\TextField`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/fpu = true,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    precision=2,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={.}
}

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathparse{1+2}
    \makebox[0pt]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
    \begin{Form}
        \TextField[value={\pgfmathresult}]{}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image].

## Question

- Am I thinking in the wrong direction?
- Why is `\pgfmathprintnumber` throwing an error if used as value in `\TextField`?
- Is there a better way to get the result of `\pgfmathresult` pretty printed in value of `\TextField`?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the printing command in a command. But it will contain things that are actually not allowed in a textfield. So you will see warnings like

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 23.
```

So don't rely on pretting printing to do the right thing in a textfield.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/fpu = true,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    precision=2,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={.}
}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{1+2}
\pgfmathprintnumberto{\pgfmathresult}\mytmpa
\begin{Form}
        \TextField[value=\mytmpa]{lbb}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the answer as a quick and dirty fix.